# Raspberry Pi SSH lag slowness

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, tmux

I am experiencing issues with the Pi, when I try to work on the Pi trough SSH I suddenly get lageness. At the beginning it works fine, but intermittently the auto-complete or commands on the history take a long time to load and that affects the typing.

How can I find out what is doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading around I found that could be an issue with network, the SD card R/W speeds or even the SSH configuration itself, nothing that I tried of what I found around worked for me which was quite disappointing.

I don't know which the problem was exactly on my case.

I found a solution for me thanks to that several time my SSH session dropped an this is particularly painful If on the middle of running a command, so i decided to look for a way to keep session alive independently I found tmux. Which no only allowed me to keep session alive but it improved my ssh response, I read that mosh would do the same but I decided to go with tmux which work perfectly for me.

Comment: Any idea why tmux would make a difference?

Comment: No idea, I'm assuming it's because the way it's built maybe adding a bigger quicker buffer. But it work for me and it even help me when working from different PCs or coming back to a session, it's really good... have you tried it? what was your experience?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this answer [here](https://johnpili.com/fix-raspberry-pi-ssh-freezing-issue/#:%7E:text=If%20your%20SSH%20connection%20to,the%20example%20configuration%20file%20below).

For me that solves the issue. The system was a Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm on a Raspberry Pi 4.

`sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

And add `IPQoS cs0 cs0` to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for this, I haven't seen this issue since RP 1or2 and above. I have a feeling this issue was something to do with hardware rather than configuration